# How to delete all partitions without using an operating system

Tags: partition, grub2, uefi

How to delete all partitions from my system using only the GNU Grub Terminal and BIOS

Comment: If installing a new system, you do not need to delete old partitions. You can select to overwrite everything with new install. Otherwise you need some bootable system. It could be just the gparted live installer, or any other operating system.https://gparted.org/download.php

Comment: Do you want to make sure, that nobody can read the [previous] content? Or do you simply want to prepare for using the drive for something else, for example backup or a new operating system? And what kind of drive is it (HDD, SSD, something else)?

Answer (score 0):

You need an operating system to manage any commands or processes that will erase all partitions on a disk.

Boot either a [Rescue System](https://www.system-rescue.org/) or your existing Linux system. (You can actually erase a disk from a Linux system that was booted from it, or you can [install onto a USB](https://www.system-rescue.org/Installing-SystemRescue-on-a-USB-memory-stick/) if that's not an option.)

**Confirm the disk device** to have its partition table erased. If you get this wrong you will erase the partition table on the wrong disk!

Assume the the device is `/dev/sdc`.

```
disk=/dev/sdc
[ -b "$disk" ] || echo STOP no such device
```

Provided that does not print an error

```
dd bs=32M count=1 </dev/zero >"$disk"
```

None of this erases much of the actual data on the disk; it simply removes the partition table.

Comment: So you want me to get a USB with my old os on boot it and from there delete the partitions right?

Comment: Use https://www.system-rescue.org

Comment: Agreeing with your initial statement, I am however left surprised. BIOSes would offer the possibility to enable / disable SATA secure erase feature and left unable to send the secure erase command to the devices ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thank you for the link. That's my favourite one but I didn't link to it. Done so now.

Comment: @MC68020 UEFI systems might offer the opportunity to use SATA Secure Erase but I didn't think BIOS systems could do so. If if I'm wrong on that count it still requires SE to be implemented on the target disk (not guaranteed by any means). All in all I prefer the "manual" approach

Comment: For GPT-partitioned drives, you'd also want to wipe the backup table at the end of the device.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I wondered about that. Do you know if it gets picked up automatically by either Linux-based tools and/or Windows tools?

Comment: `gdisk` at least detects the backup table and offers you to use that to recover the partitions.